# Xcode 13.4.1 simulator kills internet

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I'm currently running Xcode 13.4.1 and simulator 15.5. Internet goes down when I build and run any app through the simulator. It restores back once I quit the simulator.

[Tried this but didn't work](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691888)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on macOS 12.0.1, Xcode 13.4.1. Network Link Conditioner was installed but disabled.
Tried to reinstall Xcode & Simulators, but no luck.

Only **updating macOS to 12.5.1 resolved the issue**.